# Как в pytest запустить test suit несколько раз с разными параметрами?

Tags: python, pytest

У меня есть около 5-6 тестов в каждом модуле. Понадобилось запускать их все с разными входными параметрами. Т.е. только во время первого теста указывается разрешения и другие параметры, дальше их менять не нужно. Пробовал parametrize, но со scope='moudle' он у меня не заработал. А без него он просто запускает тест несколько раз и идет дальше, а мне нужно повторить весь модуль. Есть ли какой-то вариант?
Вот так это примерно выглядит:

```
@pytest.fixture
def foo():
    print('foo')


@pytest.fixture
def bar():
    print('bar')


@pytest.fixture
def arg(request):
    return request.getfixturevalue(request.param)


@pytest.mark.parametrize('arg', ['foo', 'bar'], indirect=True, scope='module')
def test_me(arg):
    print(arg)


def test_another_one():
    print('This is the second test')
```

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался, нужно было добавить разные параметры как фикстуру, которую нужно прописать в каждом тесте:

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def foo():
    print('\nfoo\nfoo\nfoo')


@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def bar():
    print('\nbar\nbar\nbar')


@pytest.fixture(params=['foo', 'bar'], scope='module')
def arg(request):
    return request.getfixturevalue(request.param)


def test_one(arg):
    assert True


def test_two(arg):
    print('This is the second test')
```